# Receiving questionable money Email Transfer

Tags: money-transfer, scams

I have recently been offer a job as Account Technician, it's all done online.  The job seems true with job search out and a decent webpage.  My question is they want me to accept money thru Bitcoin or Email transfer thru my bank account and move it all to another Bitcoin account.  Is this legitimate?

Comment: They want you to get payed and then send some money to a different account? Sounds like a scam.

Comment: If you're in the US, the Federal Trade Commission has a Complaint Assistant
https://www.ftccomplaintassistant.gov/#crnt&panel1-1

Comment: I've never worked a job where getting paid involved more than **me** telling **them** where to put the money. Just sayin'. Also, Bitcoin?!  Who wants to get paid in Bitcoin?  Last I checked, Bitcoin had transaction fees, which means it costs you money *just to spend your money.*

Answer (score 11):

This is likely a scam. This is typically how fraudsters recruit money mules, by posing as some sort of business. Many have very "realistic" webpages and recruiters. Just remember, no legitimate business should ever need to move money via personal accounts of employees. Heck, any account or email you gave them is now suspect and you should change them. If you needed to give out a Social Security number, you should freeze your credit and monitor all accounts you have.

Comment: Please delete the word "likely" :-(

Answer (score 2):

That's not a real job.  That's a scam.

### It's a [fake "check" scam](https://www.bbb.org/article/scams/14042-bbb-tip-fake-check-scams)...

The money inbound to your account will seem legitimate, but will later reverse "bounce".  The money outbound from your account will be irrevocable.

For instance, they will transfer $12,000 in, and have you transfer $10,000 out, and you're told the $2000 is yours to keep.   Later, the $12,000 will reverse, leaving your account overdrawn by $10,000.  Your bank will come after you for that, and you will say "try to recover the $10,000” and they will try and be unable.

When you are unable to give them $10,000, they will start litigation against you and will also mark you in the ChexSystems blacklist.  The knock-on effects of this will be a low credit score, and you will not be able to open a checking account for 7 years.  This will make you among the  "unbanked".  If you wonder who willingly pays 7% to have their checks cashed at those pink check-cashing shops, that's who.

### The money is from hacked accounts...

Many kinds of hacked accounts could be involved.  That can include hacked bank accounts, or Social Security accounts - many seniors don't bother signing up for Social Security's online account, so hackers do it for them, and redirect their SS payments to somewhere else... That's where you and your account comes in. This type of fraud takes months to unravel, and so may roll for awhile.  Later, when SS catches up with you, if they can't immediately claw it back, well, they have your number.  and they can wait.  When you retire and they're paying you your Social Security payments, they can tap it.

### ... Or money laundering

There's an outside possibility the money is genuine and will remain in your account.  Unfortunately, the source of the money is crime, and it's likely to be tailed by Police , DEA or Secret Service.  They will confiscate all of the $12,000 they can get.  They might also try to prosecute you for money laundering, but you'll likely be able to get out of that.

Regardless, even if *everything* was legit, doing what they want you to do would be a violation of other banking laws which are designed to prevent money laundering, since you are acting as a bank.

The $10,000 has been *laundered*, and will go on to be used for bad things.  Not least, this is how terror is financed.

Comment: By "take it out of your Social Security account" I presume you actually mean "deduct it from your future Social Security payments"?  There are no individual accounts.  (Further confused because earlier in the same paragraph, you used "account" to mean "login credentials", but those only represent control over payments and information, not a monetary balance that could be debited)

Comment: @BenVoigt I was trying to simplify it and didn't.  Good point, edited.